# calculate the predicted value based on coefficient and constant in python

Tags: python, regression, pandas, predict

i have the coefficients and the constant (alpha). i want to multiply and add the values together like this example. (it has to be done for 300000 rows)

> Prediction = constant + (valOfRow1 * col1) + (-valOfRow1  *
> col2) + (-valOfRow1 * col3) + (valOfRow1 *
> col4) + (valOfRow1 * col5)

i have a one row dataframe which contains the coefficient and constant like this

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | constant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2.447697e-07 | -5.214072e-07 | -0.000003 | 0.000006 | 555 | 222 |

and another dataframe with the exact same name but with monthly values.

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16711 | 17961 | 0 | 20 | 55 |

i already tried to sort the columns and then i take the product of them `df.dot`.

```
selected_columns = selected_columns.sort_index(axis=1)
#mean_coefficients dataframe 21th (starting from 0) is constant so i use the other columns
selected_columns['predicted_Mcap']=selected_columns.dot(mean_coefficients.iloc[:,0:20])+mean_coefficients['const']
```

`mean_coefficients.columns`
result:
`['CashSTInv_w', 'CommonEquity_w', 'GainLossAssetSale_w', 'IncomeTaxes_w', 'LTDebt_w', 'NIbefEIPrefDiv_w', 'NIbefPrefDiv_w', 'NItoCommon_w', 'OtherCA_w', 'OtherCL_w', 'OtherIncome_w', 'OtherLiabilities_w', 'OtherTA_w', 'PPT_w', 'PreTaxIncome_w', 'PrefDiv_w', 'Sales_w', 'TotalAssets', 'TotalDiv_w', 'TotalLiabilities_w', 'const']`

the reason that i use `mean_coefficients.iloc[:,0:20]` is because i don't want to conclude `const` in the multiplication it just needs to be added at the end.please pay attention that my constant (alpha) is saved in `mean_coefficients`.

`selected_columns.columns`
result:
`['CashSTInv_w', 'CommonEquity_w', 'GainLossAssetSale_w', 'IncomeTaxes_w', 'LTDebt_w', 'NIbefEIPrefDiv_w', 'NIbefPrefDiv_w', 'NItoCommon_w', 'OtherCA_w', 'OtherCL_w', 'OtherIncome_w', 'OtherLiabilities_w', 'OtherTA_w', 'PPT_w', 'PreTaxIncome_w', 'PrefDiv_w', 'Sales_w', 'TotalAssets', 'TotalDiv_w', 'TotalLiabilities_w']`

so i calculated the predicted value but when i checked it in excel the value wasn't the same.

am i calculating it right?

Answer (score 0):

As mentions in `df.dot()` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html#:%7E:text=The%20dimensions%20of%20DataFrame%20and%20other%20must%20be%20compatible%20in%20order%20to%20compute%20the%20matrix%20multiplication.%20In%20addition%2C%20the%20column%20names%20of%20DataFrame%20and%20the%20index%20of%20other%20must%20contain%20the%20same%20values%2C%20as%20they%20will%20be%20aligned%20prior%20to%20the%20multiplication.) the column names of DataFrame and the index of other must contain the same values, as they will be aligned prior to the multiplication. Otherwise you'll get

> ValueError: matrices are not aligned

so you have 2 Options:

to use the `df.dot()` with the `.T` or transposed dataframe. Your column names will be as indexes and is ready to be multiplied in a matrix way. Remember that the Column names in both dataframes has to be the same. Even one extra column returns error.

```
selected_columns['predicted_MCAP']=selected_columns.dot(mean_coefficients.iloc[:,1:21].T) + mean_coefficients['const']
```

in order to workaround this i by using numpy array

```
result = df1.dot(df2.values)
```